# Are $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$ sets are related?

Tags: measure-theory

Friends

I was just curious while reading about $G_{\delta}$ and $F_{\sigma}$ sets,

Where $G_{\delta}$ set is defined as countable intersection of Open sets and

$F_{\sigma}$ set is defined as countable union of closed sets

Just by seeing the definition i concluded $(F_{\sigma})^{c} = G_{\delta}$, where $A^{c}$ means complement of $A$.

Is this correct or i am lacking something ?

Comment: If by $(F_{\sigma})^{c} = G_{\delta}$, you mean the complement of an $F_\sigma$ set is a $G_\delta$ set, then yes you are correct, and the proof is trivial.

Comment: If $A^c$ means the complement of $A$, then $(F_\sigma)^c$ should mean the complement of $F_\sigma$. So you have to first tell us what this set $F_\sigma$ is, and in what larger set are we taking its complement. (Or perhaps you didn't write what you meant.)

Comment: Saying that larger set is any set $X$ would not be a correct way , so let it be defined in $\mathbb{R}$ @arjafi

Comment: And i think this is correct , is it -- "$F_{\sigma}$ set is defined as collection of countable union of closed sets"

Comment: So are you asking "If a set is not $F_\sigma$, then it is $G_\delta$?" i.e. taking complements in the power set of $\mathbb R$?  If that's the case, the answer is no, as any singleton is both $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$.

Comment: Now i am confused , as i saw the statement stated in the question in my notebook but i never thought about larger set ,what do you think about the larger set @Aweygan

Comment: I think the burden of clarification is on you.  Either cite the book, or pick a context yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly. If you identify $F_{\sigma},G_{\delta}$ with sets family it's wrong. What is true is that $$ A\in F_{\sigma}\iff A^c\in G_{\delta}$$